# This is the sentence that has made me wonder usage of 'to infinitive'

Tags: infinitives

This is the sentence that has made me wonder usage of 'to infinitive'.

> 1. We have three session to learn about history.

And I think this sentence is the same meaning as the following 2 sentences, which is more familiar with me.

> 2. We have three sessions where we learn about history.
> 3. We have three sessions in which we learn about history.

## Q1. So, can I use which sentence I like to use among #1,2 and 3 because they are interchangable?

And I looked it up on the internet to understand how to use 'to infinitive', especially ones that is used to modify a noun right after it. And I've made the two sentences that I think is better than #1 grammatically.

> 4. We have three sessions in which (for us) to learn about history.
> 5. We have three session (for us) to learn about history in.

## Q2. I think #1 has to be replaced with 5, adding 'in' at the end of the sentence because when we remove 'which' in #4 we need to let 'in(preposition)' be at the end of the phrase. Am I right to think this way?

ps. Can I add 'for us' to clarify the sentence in #4,5?

Comment: There is no need for "in" at the end of the sentence: "The train is leaving soon. We have ten minutes *to reach the train platform*.  We have three sessions *to learn about this dynasty*".

Comment: "For us" is not grammatical nor is it necessary to clarify the sentence.

Comment: 1.We have three sessions in which we can learn about history.
2. We have three sessions in which we learn about history. which one is more suitable for this original sentence?

Comment: Flip a coin.   *three sessions to learn about* suggests a future planned opportunity to learn.  The version with "can" echoes the opportunity element; the version without "can" (i.e. "in which we learn") echoes the planned element.

Comment: BTW In all these sentences in should be "three sessions", not "three session".

Comment: Then, "We have three session to study history." is the same as "We have three sessions where we are available for the purpose of studying history". right?

Comment: Our availability is not the issue. The *sessions* are available. There will be those three opportunities.